# Showing that X and Y are not Independent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Here is the question
[image]
I am on my second week of learning inferential statistics at a high pace, so I apologize if this is a trivial question.

How exactly would I approach this? I have written out the pdf, so I can visualize it easier:

$$f_{X,Y}({x,y})=\begin{cases} 1/\pi, & \text{if $x^2 + y^2 <1$} \\ 0, & \text{o.w.} \end{cases}$$

Also, (I don't know if this is completely right). I thought a good first step would be to write out the marginal pdf equations because my intuition tells me this may be the way to go about it. I may need to add that I am brushing up on solving my integrals because I do not know what the low bound would be or if I am even thinking of this correctly.

$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int 1/\pi dy $$

$$f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X,Y}(x,y)dx=\int 1/\pi dx$$

Comment: I''m not clear what $X,Y$ are.  Are they the random variables which pick out the relevant coordinate of a randomly selected point $(x,y)$?  If so, then they obviously aren't independent.  If $X=1$ then $Y=0$ with probability $1$, for example.

Comment: For intuition, consider the same problem on the unit square $[0,1]\times [0,1]$  In that case, the coordinate variables *are* independent since, for any possible value of $X$, $Y$ is uniform on $[0,1]$.

Comment: $X$ can't be $1$ though since then $x^2+y^2\not <1$ ..?

Comment: @Jellyfish  Fair enough ( read the support as $≤1$).  So just take $X=.99999$, or, if you prefer, $X\in (.99998,.99999)$. Then $Y$ is supported on an extremely small neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: That is what I was going to say. I think I have figured this one out. Correct me if I am wrong, but the sum of x and Y can never be negative because they are both squared and they cannot be 1. That means I should integrate from 0 to 1. That leaves me with $1/\pi$ for each marginal pdf. Those multiplied do not equal the joint pdf , which makes them dependent.

Comment: That does not make sense. the point  $(-.1,-.1)$ is in the support of your distribution.

Comment: I guess we do not have to make this too complicated. It is just the uniform distribution on the open unit disk on 2D plane...

Comment: Like I mentioned originally. I want to find the upper and lower bounds of this integral. If it cannot be more than 1 that means the lower bound would be -1 (close to it) and the upper would be 1 (again, close to it) correct? I want to show my work through integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea is correct. The most important thing here is to figure out the bounds for integration.

To calculate $f_X(x)$ at a fixed point $x_0$, we need to integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over $-\infty$ to $\infty$ along the vertical line $x=x_0$. But definitely, $f_{X,Y}$ is not always nonzero on the line, so the integral is actually taken on the *support* of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, i.e., the ranges of $y$ for $x=x_0$ that makes $f_{X,Y}$ nonzero.

In your specific example, for $|X|\geq 1$, there is no such $y$ that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is nonzero.

For $|X|<1$, the support is $$\{y\mid x^2+y^2<1\}=\{y\mid-\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\sqrt{1-x^2}\}=(-\sqrt{1-x^2},\sqrt{1-x^2}).$$
Thus you only need to take integral over that limits:
$$f_X(x)=\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\frac{1}{\pi}dy}=\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\pi}.$$
In general,
$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases} 2\sqrt{1-x^2}/\pi, & -1<x<1 \\ 0, & |x|\geq 1 \end{cases}$$ You may check that this is a valid pdf.

After you get $f_Y(y)$, you just need to check if $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. If they are not equal, then $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.

Answer (score 1):

$$f_{X,Y}({x,y})=\begin{cases} 1/\pi, & \text{if $x^2 + y^2 <1$} \\ 0, & \text{o.w.} \end{cases}$$

The support is the unit disc, and can be written $y^2<1-x^2$.   So for a given value of $x$ for $X$ (in $[-1..1]$), the value for $Y$ will lie in the range $[-\surd(1-x^2)..\surd(1-x^2)]$: $$f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle\int_{-\surd(1-x^2)}^{\surd(1-x^2)}\frac 1\pi\,\mathrm d y&:& {x\in[-1..1]}\\[1ex]0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

---

However, you do not need calculate that as range of realisable values of $Y$ clearly *depends* on the realised value of $X$, so we *immediately* know these random variables are **dependent**.

Example: the point event $\langle X,Y\rangle=\langle 0.75,0.75\rangle$ has a zero probability density (it lies outside the disc), where as the point events $X=0.75$ and $Y=0.75$ each have a non-zero marginal probability density (the  lines perpendicular to the axis through them do intersect the disc).

Hence $\lnot\forall x\,\forall y~.f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x)\,f_{Y}(x)$

---

But of course it is simply $$f_{X}(x)=\begin{cases}\tfrac 2\pi \surd(1-x^2)&:& {x\in[-1..1]}\\[1ex]0&:&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Likewise for $Y$, and you can show their product does not equal their joint pdf, if you really wanted to.